# Macro long string concernation

Tags: c++, string, macros

In my application I want to add the version ID as a macro and use it in multiple parts of the application. As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation) I can easily generate a string with this:

```
#define APP_VER "1.0"
#define APP_CAPTION "Stackoverflow example app v." ## APP_VER
```

My problem is now, that in some parts, I need to have the caption as an unicode string.

I tried the following:

```
MessageBoxW(0,_T(APP_CAPTION),L"Minimal Counterexample",0);
```

But it gives the error "can't concernate wide 'Stackoverflow example app v.' with narrow '1.0'"

I also tried

```
#define WIDE_CAPTION L ## APP_CAPTION
```

But that just gives "LAPP_CAPTION" is not defined.

I know that I can convert the string at runtime to unicode, but that is rather messy. Can someone provide a Macro-level solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want:

```
#define APP_CAPTION "Stackoverflow example app v." APP_VER
```

Since `APP_VER` is already a string.

String concatenation happens for free, for example:

```
const char *str = "hello " "world"
```

Complete compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define APP_VER "1.0"
#define APP_CAPTION "Stackoverflow example app v." APP_VER

int main() {
  std::cout << APP_CAPTION << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that the '##' can be left out, but it doesn't fix my initial problem.

Comment: I figured it out myself, it has to be '
#define APP_CAPTION L"Stackoverflow example app v." _T(APP_VER) '

Comment: @Listing If you are using the `_T` macro, why are you using `L"..."` and the *W*ide version of functions? Try to keep consistency or you will be maintaining a mess.

Comment: Indeed, it should be `#define APP_CAPTION _T("Stack Overflow example app v." _T(APP_VER)`