# Is there a way to concatenate a string to a number without assigning a variable?

Tags: c++, macros

I need to have a string that uses a macro value which is an integer. But it's outside of any functions, so I do not want to create a variable. I'm using it in a #pragma comment.

so something like this:

```
#define num 7
#pragma comment(lib, "string" + num)
```

which would combine the string and num making it (#pragma comment(lib, "string7")

Comment: This is answered before.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation

Comment: That didn't work, and the solution in that didn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called *stringification*:

```
#define stringify_1(x...)     #x
#define stringify(x...)       stringify_1(x)

#define NUM 7

char *p = stringify(NUM);
```

This is inspired by `__stringify`  macro in `include/linux/stringify.h` in Linux kernel helpers.

Comment: He wants the pragma directive to become `comment(lib, "string7")`

Comment: I removed the `__` prefix to Linux macro names as names starting with `__*` are reserved for any use.

Comment: @oldring I don't have access to MSVC to check if `comment(lib, "string" stringify(NUM))` would work

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely clear on the intent, it sounds like some preprocessor capability:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification

From that example you find this terse explanation that seems to be what you want.

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4
str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

So you would be able to do something like this:

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define num 7
#pragma comment(lib, "string" xstr(num))
```

Normal string merging rules should make that all fine if it were in actual code, but I am not sure if the string will automatically merge in the pragma. That is probably implementation dependent.