# Converting a #defined constant number to a string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c-strings, stringification

I have a constant defined:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
```

I am trying to do this:

```
scanf("%" MAX_STR_LEN "s", p_buf);
```

But of course that doesn't work.

What preprocessor trick can be use to convert the MAX_STR_LEN numerica into a string so I can use it in the above scanf call ? Basically:

```
scanf("%" XYZ(MAX_STR_LEN) "s", p_buf);
```

What should XYZ() be ?

Note: I can of course do "%100s" directly, but that defeats the purpose. I can also do #define MAX_STR_LEN_STR "100", but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: `#define f(x) #x` will preprocess `f(foo)` into `"foo"`

Comment: You might want to look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation/5256500

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `#` preprocessing operator.  This operator only works during macro expansion, so you'll need some macros to help.  Further, due to peculiarities inherent in the macro replacement algorithm, you need a layer of indirection.  The result looks like this:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)

scanf("%" STRINGIZE(MAX_STR_LEN) "s", p_buf);
```