# Constant Definition within Constant Definition in C

Tags: c, constants

I'm trying to use a constant definition in another constant definition like so:

```
#define ADDRESS 5002
#define FIND "foundaddress ADDRESS"
```

But this includes ADDRESS in the FIND constant when I want the constant FIND to be foundaddress 5002.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `#define FIND "found address"ADDRESS`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind changeing ADDRESS to a string, you can use the preprocessor concatenation

```
#define ADDRESS "5002" /* rather than 5002 without quotes */
#define FIND "foundaddress " ADDRESS
```

The compiler will see that 2nd line as

```
#define FIND "foundaddress 5002"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the preprocessor stringification operator to make your value into a string, then concatenate them like others have said.

```
#define ADDRESS_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define ADDRESS 5002
#define FIND "foundaddress " ADDRESS_TO_STRING(ADDRESS)
```

And if that gives you "foundaddress ADDRESS", it means you need one more layer:

```
#define ADDRESS_TO_STRING_(x) #x
#define ADDRESS_TO_STRING(x) ADDRESS_TO_STRING_(x)
#define ADDRESS 5002
#define FIND "foundaddress " ADDRESS_TO_STRING(ADDRESS)
```

Comment: " if that gives you ..." -- It must if you're using a conforming C implelentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
#define ADDRESS "5002"
#define FIND "foundaddress " ADDRESS
```

Comment: For it to work in GCC I needed to `#define ADDRESS "5002"` though.

Answer (score 0):

From [C/C++ Macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation/5256500)

```
/*
 * Turn A into a string literal without expanding macro definitions
 * (however, if invoked from a macro, macro arguments are expanded).
 */
#define STRINGIZE_NX(A) #A

/*
 * Turn A into a string literal after macro-expanding it.
 */
#define STRINGIZE(A) STRINGIZE_NX(A)
```

Then

```
#define FIND ("foundaddress " STRINGIZE(ADDRESS))
```

produces ("foundaddress " "5002") which should be usable wherever you need a string literal, due to C's string literal concatenation.