# Custom Preprocessor Macro for a conditional #pragma message "xxx"

Tags: xcode, preprocessor, pragma

I use this throughout my code:

```
#pragma message "FIXME: this needs to be fixed"
```

I want these warning messages to only show up for users who enabled them. I thought I'll just write a macro for it, like:

```
#ifdef SHOW_DEVELOPER_MESSAGES
#define DEVELOPER_MESSAGE(msg) _Pragma("message " ## msg)
#endif
```

And use it like this:

```
DEVELOPER_MESSAGE("TEST: -- xxxx --")
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Pasting formed '"message ""TEST: -- xxxxx --"', an invalid preprocessing token
```

I have read [C/C++ Macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation) and tried to use it but I couldn't get it to work. I'm thinking this has to do that the message needs to be in escaped quotes like so (this one works I just don't know how to create an escaped string like this that works with _Pragma):

```
_Pragma("message \"THIS is the actual message!\"")
```

How do I create a macro that prints out a pragma message (or comparable solution)?

The solution should be a one-liner, enclosing each pragma message with `#ifdef SHOW_DEVELOPER_MESSAGES` would be defeating the purpose of this exercise.

---

**Bonus question:** How would I need to change the macro to create different variants for different message types, for example:

```
DEVELOPER_FIXME("bug")
```

Which always prefixes the string with FIXME to form: `"FIXME: bug"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(With help from http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-10/msg00194.html):

```
#ifdef SHOW_DEVELOPER_MESSAGES
#define PRAGMA_MESSAGE(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define DEVELOPER_MESSAGE(msg) PRAGMA_MESSAGE(message msg)
#endif
```

Answer to bonus question:

```
#define DEVELOPER_FIXME(msg) PRAGMA_MESSAGE(message "FIXME:" msg)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! The FIXME macro doesn't work though, I get "Pragma message requires parenthesized string". I'll dabble with it some more.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Somehow by copying I had changed the macro into: #define DEVELOPER_FIXME(msg) DEVELOPER_MESSAGE(message "FIXME:" msg)