# Is it possible to "glue" preprocessor tokens in third type of #include directive into double quote?

Tags: c, c99, c-preprocessor

Consider following example:

```
#define HEADER_OPEN  <
#define HEADER_CLOSE >
#define HEADER_PATH  sys/
#define HEADER_FILE  types.h

#include HEADER_OPEN HEADER_PATH HEADER_FILE HEADER_CLOSE

int main(void)
{
    clock_t c;

    return 0;
}
```

It's more lengthy way to include `<sys/types.h>` header. The question is can I construct in similar way header with double-quotes like  `"release/myheader.h"` ? Is there any way to "escape" double-quote character, so such (final) directive can be constructed from multiple parts (not only one) ?

Comment: That could work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation

Comment: @dari: adjacent string literal tokens are concatened in translation phrase 6 (after `#include` directives are processsed), so it's "too late".

Comment: If the name of the include directory changes you can use a constant symbolic links, that points to the current directory. Not exactly the answer you are looking for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Does this really work? It does not work on MS Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: It's C99 (and `sys/types.h` is POSIX header), I wouldn't be suprised if MS haven't implemented it yet. Be sure that you are in "C mode" and try with maybe simpler construct: `#define TO_INCLUDE <stdio.h>` then `#include TO_INCLUDE`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski It works when I define `toinclude` as `<stdio.h>` but seriously, man, I think what it does makes much more sense here over my end. When I have, for example, three definitions (unlike 4 on yours), `#define open <`, `#define kek stdio.h`, and `#define close >`; it first replaces `open` with a `<`, then the rest becomes irreplaceable, taken literally as `< kek close`, awaiting for a `>` that won't ever come. For it to work as in yours, it either should start replacing from the end, do not update replace-ability during replacements phase, or replace things inside `<` and `>`

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: I understand, thanks for describing, but standard seems to be clearly definitive that all encountered macros should be replaced, C99 draft `6.10.2` (emphasis mine): "**Each**
identifier **currently defined** as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens.". However this brings me into conclusion that such `#include` with multiple macros should be rather avoided at all, especially in portable code.

Comment: So you are interpreting that as *"No updating of the replace-ability state during macro replacement phase"*. Fair enough... By looking at the warning produced, Visual Studio clearly takes it as `#include < kek close`, which means that it recognizes `kek` and `close` as irreplacable after replacing the `open`; just like how `kek` would be if I were to write `#include <kek>` both in MSVC and in your compiler (I hope).

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Almost right, the thing is that `#include <kek>` is actually "detected" as "ordinary" `#include <..>` form, so it takes `kek` literally. Looking into standard there is sentence (about third form, emphasis mine): "that does not **match** one of the two previous forms)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grzegorz' solution is almost right.

```
#define EXPAND( X ) X
#define STRINGIZE_LITERAL( X ) # X
#define STRINGIZE( X ) STRINGIZE_LITERAL( X )

#define HEADER( PATH, FILE ) STRINGIZE( EXPAND( PATH )FILE )

#include HEADER( sys/, types.h )
```

The `EXPAND` macro is used to avoid a space character between the path and the filename.

Note, the standard guarantees this to work, but not your code with angle braces, because the whitespace handling in that case is implementation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up, that almost works is a workoaround header expression, that is constructed by function-like macro (the key is to apply `#` operator at the end):

```
#define HEADER_PATH sys/
#define HEADER_FILE types.h

#define HEADER_STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define HEADER_REAL(path,file) HEADER_STRINGIZE(path##file)
#define HEADER(path,file) HEADER_REAL(path,file)

#include HEADER(HEADER_PATH, HEADER_FILE) /* the same as "sys/types.h" */

int main(void)
{
    clock_t c;

    return 0;
}
```

With `gcc -E` option I see that proper file is loaded, however preprocessor tryies to construct token of `/` and `types.h` (operator `##`), which yields into invalid token producing an error:

> check.c:8:1: error: pasting "/" and "types" does not give a valid
>   preprocessing token

Comment: This doesn't work for me; gcc gives:  `[Error] pasting "/" and "types" does not give a valid preprocessing token` at the `#include` statement.