# Token concatenation in GNU C/C++ macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I wish to write a macro to output the text of an expression and its value, e.g.

```
int a = 2;
PRINT(a + 1);
```

should output

> a + 1 = 3

[C/C++ Macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation) shows the use of token concatenation. However,

```
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << x " = " << x << "\n"
```

or

```
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << (x) " = " << x << "\n"
```

gives

> error: expected ';' before string constant

while

```
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << x##" = " << x << "\n"
```

gives

> error: pasting "1" and "" = "" does not give a valid preprocessing token

How can I achieve my aim, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single `#` before a macro parameter to turn it into a string.

Also put parentheses around normal uses of the parameter, to prevent surprising effects of operator precedence.

```
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << #x " = " << (x) << "\n"
                              ^           ^ ^
```

You don't want token concatenation here (or in the question you link to, as the answer there describes); that's not used to combine string literals (which is done automatically), but to bodge two tokens together to make a single one, for example

```
#define DECLARE_TWO_VARIABLES(x) int x ## 1, x ## 2;
DECLARE_TWO_VARIABLES(stuff)
```

expands to

```
int stuff1, stuff2;
```

concatenating `1` and `2` onto the argument `stuff` to create single tokens `stuff1` and `stuff2`.