# What is the need for __NSX_PASTE__ to define a macro?

Tags: objective-c, macros, clang, min

Let's review Clang's `MIN` macro through this article: [Deep learning IOS development of macro](http://www.programering.com/a/MDM2ATMwATI.html). The final result is [what you can also find here](https://gist.github.com/monkeydom/6834787):

```
#define __NSX_PASTE__(A,B) A##B

#define __NSMIN_IMPL__(A,B,L) ({\
        __typeof__(A) __NSX_PASTE__(__a,L) = (A);\
        __typeof__(B) __NSX_PASTE__(__b,L) = (B);\
        (__NSX_PASTE__(__a,L) < __NSX_PASTE__(__b,L)) ? __NSX_PASTE__(__a,L) : __NSX_PASTE__(__b,L);\
        })
```

But I don't understand the need of defining `__NSX_PASTE__`. Wouldn't it be the same and more readable to use directly:

```
#define __NSMIN_IMPL__(A,B,L) ({\
        __typeof__(A) __a##L = (A);\
        __typeof__(B) __b##L = (B);\
        (__a##L < __b##L) ? __a##L : __b##L;\
        })
```

Comment: Could be an attempt at macro-expanding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256500/1033581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is the `__NSX_PASTE__` is required as without it the `__COUNTER__` macro (not shown in the question but see the full source in the linked article, or look at the definition in Apple's `NSObjCRuntime.h`) will not be expanded. This is due to the weird and wonderful way the C Preprocessor works and how it handles *stringification* and *concatenation*, a good place to read how all this works is the [GCC documentation on macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros).

To see the results with and without the `__NSX_PASTE__` put your above macros in a test file, say *test.m*, in Xcode renaming `__NSMIN_IMPL__` to `MY__NSMIN_IMPL__` (or you'll get a duplicate macro warning), add the macro you omitted - again renamed to avoid clashes:

```
#define MY_MIN(A,B) MY__NSMIN_IMPL__(A,B,__COUNTER__)
```

and add some code which uses `MY_MIN`. Now in Xcode select the menu item Product > Perform Action -> Preprocess "test.m" - this will show you the result after the preprocessor has run. If you try it with your version of `__NSMIN_IMPL__` which does not use `__NSX_PASTE__` you will see `__COUNTER__` is not expanded.

HTH

Comment: Oh, fantastic demonstration with _Preprocess_ tool.