# C++ Macro for Function Name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, macros

I'm trying to create a macro that can be used to generically call CppUnitTestFramework's attributes metadata type. Since the calling convention for each test method is different because it uses the function's name in it I need to do something like this:

```
#define GetAttributes() CATNAME(CATNAME(CATNAME(__GetMethodMetadata,_),__func__),()))
```

With the hopes that when this macro is used like this:

```
...
void someFunction(){
    MethodAttributeMetadata* meta = GetAttributes();
    ...
}
```

Is processed like this:

```
...
void someFunction(){
    MethodAttributeMetadata* meta = __GetMethodMetadata_someFunction();
    ...
}
```

**Extra info:**

Compiler: Visual Studio Tools 2013 (v120)

Microsoft's macro page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Is this something I can do?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation

Comment: It should at least show him how to do what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer and it is no, you cannot do this. The problem with this approach was not the string concatenation but that **func** (or any form of it) cannot be used outside of a function, even through a layer of indirection.