# concatenating nested strings using macros

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Is there a problem doing something like this

```
#define A "world"
#define B "hello "A  // or adding a whitespace --> #define B "hello " A
```

and then using the `B` in `printf(B"!");` (added another concatenation...)?

***BTW***, using  `#define B "hello "A` without white-space is OK in C, but less so in C++11 - "invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]"

By what I know, this should be OK, since the compiler concatenates the strings (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256426/3512538)), but when writing this on eclipse, with the `#define`'s in one header file, and the `printf` in another, I get no errors, but the eclipse can't seem to recognize the `define`'s

*I know eclipse is evil, but is there a C problem in this (including misuse of language features, if this is one)?*

---

**header.h**

```
#define A "world"
#define B "hello "A
```

**c.c**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   printf("%s", B"!");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: so it's basically an eclipse IDE questions? most IDEs have a great trouble parsing C/C++ code on the fly, one of the reasons being the macros

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is not an IDE question. It is a C question raised by seeing an IDE problem that might stem from an actual problem

Comment: Did you include the header file in the c file?

Comment: @mch Obviously :-)

Comment: I do believe it's an IDE problem. It's perfectly valid C code. Anecdotal, but I was never able to run Eclipse's indexer to the point nothing is underlined red.

Comment: I'd recommend GNAT Programming Studio, which has a nice C mode (based on clang) which works... it also uses projects and doesn't have workspaces. Eclipse sucks so much... Code::Blocks isn't better.

Comment: OK, thanks guys! should I delete, close or leave the question as it is?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code (`header.h` and `c.c`) on the Eclipse, it outputted `hello world!` successfully.
My execution environment is as follows.

- OS:  macOS 10.13.5
- IDE: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), Build id 20171005-1200
- Compiler(tool chain): Linux GCC

Your code is probably correct.
If you are running Eclipse with default settings, it seems that there is a problem with eclipse as you said.

---