# Conditional #define in C

Tags: c, macros

I want to write a conditional define in C with controlled with the arguments.

Something like this:

```
#define RTL_REG(reg_name,inst)     \
    inst == 0 ? DUT_0_##reg_name : \
    inst == 1 ? DUT_1_##reg_name : \
    inst == 2 ? DUT_2_##reg_name : \
    inst == 3 ? DUT_3_##reg_name : \
    DUT_0_##reg_name
```

But the code isn't working the way I want. Essentially it is substituting the value of inst for the define.

What I a, looking for is:

```
RTL_REG(CLK_EN,0) -> *DUT_0_CLK_EN*

RTL_REG(CLK_EN,1) -> *DUT_1_CLK_EN*
```

What I am getting:

```
RTL_REG(CLK_EN,0) -> 0
```

Can you some C experts help me out here?

Note:
Tried adding () as well at the beginning and ending of the definition, but then again, "(" comes in the define substitution!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ Macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation) (see second answer)

Comment: and *what is* `DUT_0_CLK_EN` then?

Comment: Taken in isolation, the macro definition in the question converts `RTL_REG(CLK_EN,0)` into `0 == 0 ? DUT_0_CLK_EN : 0 == 1 ? DUT_1_CLK_EN : 0 == 2 ? DUT_2_CLK_EN : 0 == 3 ? DUT_3_CLK_EN : DUT_0_CLK_EN` which is what you want.  However, if `DUT_0_CLK_EN` is itself defined as an object-like macro, then you will get further changes.  Also, coding safety guidelines for macros suggests you should use `((inst) == 0) ? …` in the macro definition, and probably a set of parentheses around the whole expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
#define RTL_REG(reg_name,inst) DUT_##inst##_##reg_name
```

`##` is used to concatenating two tokens. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor does not support conditional expressions (like `?:`). Instead, use a separate function macro to join the components:

```
#define  JOIN4(a, b, c, d)    a##b##c##d
#define  RTL_REG(name, inst)  JOIN4(DUT_, inst, _, name)
```

With that, `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 0)` expands to `DUT_0_CLK_EN`, and `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 1)` expands to `DUT_1_CLK_EN`.

The function-like macro call means that the macro arguments are evaluated by the preprocessor before the concatenation. This means that if you add a definition like

```
#define  CLK_EN  CLOCK_ENABLE
```

then `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 2)` expands to `DUT_2_CLOCK_ENABLE`. If you further add

```
#define  DUT_  WEIRDPREFIX_
```

then `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 3)` expands to `WEIRDPREFIX_3_CLOCK_ENABLE`.

---

Let's say you cannot use the same prefix (`DUT_0`, `DUT_1`). No worries; you just need to add one layer of function-like macro calls, and redefine the prefixes:

```
#define  JOIN3_(a, b, c)      a ## b ## c
#define  JOIN3(a, b, c)       JOIN3_(a, b, c)
#define  RTL_REG(name, inst)  JOIN3(DUT_ ## inst, _, name)
```

Then, if you do say these additional definitions,

```
#define  DUT_0   FIRST
#define  DUT_1   SECOND
#define  CLK_EN  CLOCK_ENABLE
```

then `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 0)` expands to `FIRST_CLOCK_ENABLE`, and `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 1)` to `SECOND_CLOCK_ENABLE`.  And, of course, if you do additional definitions like

```
#define  FIRST_CLOCK_ENABLE   foo(1)
#define  SECOND_CLOCK_EANBLE  bar(2)
```

then `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 0)` indeed expands to `foo(1)`, and `RTL_REG(CLK_EN, 1)` to `bar(2)`.

You just need to be careful if the intermediate terms are already defined as macros, to not get too surprised.  If you are using GCC, you can run `gcc -dD -E source-or-header-file` to obtain the preprocessed source that includes all macro definition statements.