# How to define a C macro that uses another macro?

Tags: c, macros

I have the following scenario...

Header file:

```
#define TRIG_INDEX 200    
#define PATH(target_p) some.path.to.target##target_p
```

Source file:

```
read_from_target(PATH(TRIG_INDEX));
```

As the `PATH` macro appends the `target_p` to the text at the end, compilation fails as
`some.path.to.targetTRIG_INDEX` is not a valid path.

I was expecting to get `read_from_target(some.path.to.target200)` in the above scenario.

How can I (if at all) define the macros to accept such scenario?

Comment: You need an extra expansion step for that, see the second case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735957) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument must be expanded by the macro:

```
#define TRIG_INDEX 200
#define PATH_TARGET(x) some.path.to.target##x
#define PATH(target_p) PATH_TARGET(target_p)
```

Answer (score 3):

The pre-processor macro expansion/replacement rules for function-like macros are rather intricate. Basically it does so in the following order:

- The stuff after the macro name is known as the *replacement list*. In this case `PATH_TARGET(target_p)` - things that `PATH` should be replaced with.
- The occurrence of `##` or `#` together with a macro parameter means that the parameter gets replaced with its corresponding pre-processor token sequence (if applicable). In this case, the parameter `target_p` gets replaced with `TRIG_INDEX`, so we get `some.path.to.target##TRIG_INDEX` creating the new pre-processor token `some.path.to.targetTRIG_INDEX` , which is not as intended.
- Other macro parameters get expanded. Doesn't apply here.
- The replacement list is then *rescanned* for macro names to expand, but it's too late since pre-processor token concatenation with `##` has already occurred.

The part "other macro parameters get expanded" above is useful to fix the problem. So macro *parameters*  in the replacement list take precedence over macro *names*. We can take advantage of this by adding a helper macro:

```
#define TRIG_INDEX 200
#define EXPAND(tgt) some.path.to.target##tgt
#define PATH(target_p) EXPAND(target_p)
```

Now in the expansion of the replacement list of `PATH`, we first get macro parameter expansion: `taget_p` is replaced and we get `EXPAND(TRIG_INDEX)`. The replacement list is then rescanned for macro names to replace, the pre-processor finds two such macro names: `EXPAND` and `TRIG_INDEX`. Both are expanded and so `TRIG_INDEX` is replaced with `200`. Then `EXPAND` is expanded recursively according to the same rules (`##` enforcing an expansion of that macro parameter `tgt` into `200` before anything else).

For details, see the C17 standard chapter 6.10.3 - this chapter is also the one which specifies the behavior of the # and ## operators.