# snprintf using format specifier in the string getting copied

Tags: c, linux

I created the below program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define TESTER "name=%s "

int main(){
    char *x;
    x = malloc(100);
    snprintf(x, 100, "Heyaa tester %s", TESTER, "hello");
    printf("%s", x);
    free(x)
    return 0;
}
```

I am basically trying to get the output something like - "Hey tester name=hello", However, it seems to be like below:

`Heyaa tester name=%s`

Do I need to append `hello` initially to the macro and then do `snprintf` to the malloc'd variable.

Thanks.

Comment: This will not work as you intended. This is practically `snprintf(x, 100, "Heyaa tester %s", "name=%s ", "hello");`. So you substitute the first `%s` with `"name=%s "` and the `"hello"` is basically ignored. What you could do is `snprintf(x, 100, "Heyaa tester"TESTER, "hello");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eraklon pointed out, though the Macro is expanded in the pre-processor, it's attached to the format specifier during compilation.

You can modify that line to the below and this will work.

```
snprintf(x, 100, "Heyaa tester " TESTER, "hello");
```

Here, the macro is expanded in pre-processor, then we are doing a string concatenation and after that the format specifier will pick up `"hello"` during compilation.

Just FYI:
Macro and string, string and string, macro and macro can be concatenated just using a space in between. The compiler treats adjacent strings as single string. **But beware it won't work with a string variable.**

For further reading:
[C/C++ macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation)

Comment: "Token pasting" is the use of the `##` preprocessor operator to create a new token. The rest of those things are not token pasting. And string concatenation is performed *after* preprocessing.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the info. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the macro as part of the format specifier of `snprintf()` where it expands to `"name=%s "` at the time of pre-processor itself and the concatenated string `"Heyaa tester name=%s"` is created. What you have in the OP, makes `name=%s` as a literal string that will undergo `%s` formatting treatment by `snprintf()`

```
snprintf(x, 100, "Heyaa tester " TESTER, "hello");
```

Your original attempt should have been caught as suspicious, if you enabled extra warnings flag in your compiler as `printf()` would have thrown a warning too many arguments but not enough specifiers found (`[-Wformat-extra-args]` with gcc).

And as a better coding practice always clean up the memory allocated dynamically by the program instead of letting the OS doing it and always compile your program with extra warning flags.

Comment: it is not the sollution as `char * TESTER =  "name=%s ";` will not work.

Comment: @P__J__: Am sorry could you add more details to your comment. I can't see to understand what you are implying

Comment: @P__J__ Yes. I agree. It won't work with a variable. But here Macro is used. So it'd be fine.