# how can i solve this problem preprocessor?

Tags: c, undefined, preprocessor

as i want to concatenate bits together to be 0b0000 1110 but the output in the intermediate file is 0b0000B3B2B1B0

```
#include<stdio.h>



#define conc(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0) ob##0000##bit3##bit2##bit1##bit0
#ifdef conc
#undef conc
#define B0  0
#define B1  1
#define B2  1
#define B3  1
#endif

#define conc(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0) ob##0000##bit3##bit2##bit1##bit0
int main()
{
    int z=conc(B3,B2,B1,B0);
    printf(z);
}
```

Comment: First, fix the printing: `printf(z);` --> `printf("%8.8X\n",z);` If you had compiled with `-Wall`, your `printf` would have been flagged by the compiler. You're using `ob` and _not_ `0b` as the prefix, so that's another issue.

Comment: [You need an extra layer of preprocessor abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256500/3386109).

Comment: ok, but my question is about preprocessor phase only not compilation phase @CraigEstey

Comment: Follow the link from user3386109 or _don't_ abuse things and do: `#define S(_shf,_bit) (_bit << _shf) #define conc(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0) S(3,bit3) | S(2,bit2) | S(1,bit1) | S(0,bit0)` But, honestly, although possible, what you're trying to do is "too cute". If I found it via a code review [in a commerical setting], I'd fix/remove it. Or: `static inline unsigned conc(unsigned b3,unsigned b2,unsigned b1,unsigned b0) { return (b3 << 3) | (b2 << 2) | (b1 << 1) | (b0 << 0); }`

Comment: Echoing what others have suggested: if you have to ask for help to write it, others will ask for help to *read* it.  Aim for clarity rather than clever.

Comment: Irrelevant to the problem, but wrong: The first word of your replacement text is `ob` (lower case 'Oh'), but I'm sure you want `0b` (zero).

Comment: thanks it works  
#include<stdio.h>

#define B0  0
#define B1  1
#define B2  1
#define B3  1

#define conc(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0)      conc_help(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0)

#define conc_help(bit3,bit2,bit1,bit0) ob##0000##bit3##bit2##bit1##bit0



int main()
{
 int z=conc(B3,B2,B1,B0); // instead of (1,1,1,0) directly
 printf("%d",z);